# overlapping div in Zurb Foundation

Tags: css, html, css-position, zurb-foundation, grid-layout

I have just started using Foundation by Zurb today and so far i like it very much. It makes building a website really fast. I already saw how to create rows with the number of columns i prefer and nested columns. Now i have a question though. Before using Foundation i was developing a website that was made of a wrapper containing a header with a nav menu and a div with an image slider that was overlapping the header and partially overlapping the underlining section of the website where the main content is displayed. I did that by using relative positioning with fixed pixels. Now using Foundation can i recreate the same positioning? The website i'm doing with Foundation is responsive till now so i would like to keep the responsiveness. I think i can't use pixels, so should i use percentages for defining the properties top and right of the div? I'm not sure how to do because the grid is made of columns. I attach an image of what i would like to obtain, in order to make it clearer. This is just a simple mockup but you should be able to understand.

[image]

Here it is the page that is being developed by using Foundation:

[image]
[image]

Html of the page developed with Foundation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

  <title>Welcome to Foundation | Homepage</title>

  <!-- Included CSS Files (Uncompressed) -->
  <!--
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/foundation.css">
  -->

  <!-- Included CSS Files (Compressed) -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/foundation.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css">

  <script src="javascripts/modernizr.foundation.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Header and Nav -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="three columns">
      <h1><img src="images/logo.png" /></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="nine columns">
      <ul class="nav-bar right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Il centro</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lo staff</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mappa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contatti</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- End Header and Nav -->


  <!-- First Band (Slider) -->
  <!-- The Orbit slider is initialized at the bottom of the page by calling .orbit() on     #slider -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="three columns">
      <span class="secondary label" style="font-size:26px;">Servizi</span>
      <ul class="nav-bar vertical accordion">
        <li>
          <div class="title">
            <h5>Chinesiterapia</h5>
          </div>
          <ul class="content">
            <li><a href="#">Riabilitazione perineale</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fisiokinesiterapia segmentaria</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Chinesiterapia globale</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ginnastica correttiva</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Recupero post traumatico</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ginnastica di gruppo per adulti</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Rieducazione posturale globale</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="title">
            <h5>Massoterapia</h5>
          </div>
          <ul class="content">
            <li><a href="#">Massaggio manuale</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Linfodrenaggio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Massaggio connettivale</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="title">
            <h5>Terapia fisica</h5>
          </div>
          <ul class="content">
            <li><a href="#">Elettroterapia galvanica</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Elettroterapia faradica</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Elettroterapia interferenziale</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Correnti diadinamiche</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Elettrostimolazioni</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ionoforesi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Radarterapia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ultrasuoni</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Magnetoterapia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Laserterapia CO2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test muscolare</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tecarterapia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Horizontal therapy</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="six columns">
      <div id="slider">
        <img src="images/1.png" />
        <img src="images/2.png" />
        <img src="images/3.png" />
        <img src="images/4.png" />
      </div>

      <hr />
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Three-up Content Blocks -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="nine columns">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300&text=[img]" />
      <h4>This is a content section.</h4>
      <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet nulla ham qui sint exercitation eiusmod commodo, chuck   duis velit. Aute in reprehenderit, dolore aliqua non est magna in labore pig pork biltong.   Eiusmod swine spare ribs reprehenderit culpa. Boudin aliqua adipisicing rump corned beef.  </p>
    </div>

    <div class="three columns">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300&text=[img]" />
      <h4>This is a content section.</h4>
      <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet nulla ham qui sint exercitation eiusmod commodo, chuck duis velit. Aute in reprehenderit, dolore aliqua non est magna in labore pig pork biltong. Eiusmod swine spare ribs reprehenderit culpa. Boudin aliqua adipisicing rump corned beef.  </p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Call to Action Panel -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">

      <div class="panel">
        <h4>Get in touch!</h4>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="nine columns">
            <p>We'd love to hear from you, you attractive person you.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="three columns">
            <a href="#" class="radius button right">Contact Us</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


   <!-- Footer -->

   <footer class="row">
     <div class="twelve columns">
      <hr />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="six columns">
          <p>&copy; Copyright no one at all. Go to town.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="six columns">
          <ul class="link-list right">
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div> 
   </footer>

   <!-- Included JS Files (Uncompressed) -->
   <!--
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.mediaQueryToggle.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.forms.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.reveal.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.orbit.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.navigation.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.buttons.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.tabs.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.tooltips.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.accordion.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.alerts.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.topbar.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.joyride.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.clearing.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.magellan.js"></script>
    -->

    <!-- Included JS Files (Compressed) -->
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/foundation.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize JS Plugins -->
    <script src="javascripts/app.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).load(function() {
       $('#slider').orbit();
   });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Check this html file together with the latest version of Foundation (3.2.2).
Download it from here: http://foundation.zurb.com/download.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use [css clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) before your content div:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

or, with the header div:

```
<div id="header" class="clearfix">
```

This will give your header a dynamic height and push down your content.

Comment: I don't understand. Usually clear:both or the class clearfix is used when you want to remove the floating. It doesn't seem to help me to do what i want. Should i use this in addition to other code? If you could explain better i would appreciate it. @prium

Comment: Actually css clearfix tricks does not work like clear:both.

If I can see your site, it will help me to fix your problem. Please provide a link.

Comment: I added the html of the page and i'm using the latest version(3.2.2) of Foundation by Zurb. If you download it and put the html file into the folder you can see how it looks like and check the style. @prium

Answer (score 0):

There is no "clearfix" class in the framework only "clearing"